# Como obter o código binário de uma string sem caracteres ASCII em Python?

Tags: python, string, binary

Eu estou estudando Unicode e *encodings*. Eu entendi até agora que *Unicode* é uma estrutura chave-valor em que cada caractere é representado por um número. Exemplo:

```py
import string

alphabet=list(string.ascii_lowercase)

for letter in alphabet:
    print(letter,":",ord(letter))
```

Retorna:

```
a : 97
b : 98
c : 99
d : 100
e : 101
f : 102
g : 103
h : 104
i : 105
j : 106
k : 107
l : 108
m : 109
n : 110
o : 111
p : 112
q : 113
r : 114
s : 115
t : 116
u : 117
v : 118
w : 119
x : 120
y : 121
z : 122
```

Já o *encoding* é algo completamente diferente. Trata-se da transformação de uma *string* em *bytes*. Essa transformação pode se basear em diversas estruturas de chave-valor que podem ou não ter a chave correspondente ao valor desejado. O caractere `ä` pode ser transformado em bytes usando o codec `latin-1`, mas gera um erro se o codec utilizado for `ascii`.

Ocorre que gostaria de recuperar o valor binário de um caractere em um *codec* específico, mas não estou conseguindo porque o Python sempre imprime o caractere no lugar do byte quando o caractere existe em ASCII. Exemplo:

```py
"a".encode("latin-1")
```

Retorna:

```
b'a'
```

Quando na verdade eu esperava ver `11100001` que, pelo que li, é o código binário de `a` no *codec* `latin-1`.

Note que, quando o caractere não existe em ASCII, o Python imprime o hexadecimal (que posso depois converter em binário):

```py
café.encode("latin-1")
```

Retorna:

```
b'caf\xe9'
```

Como faço para fazer o Python imprimir o código binário (ou hexadecimal) correspondente ao caractere em vez do caractere em ASCII?

Comment: alguma sugestão de como posso melhorar minha pergunta?

Comment: Está equivocado esse conceito de que *Unicode é uma estrutura chave-valor onde caractere é representado por um número*. [Unicode é um banco de dados](https://www.unicode.org/Public/13.0.0/ucd/) dividido em 16 *code planes* separados em um total de 163 *blocos* de *code points* catalogando informações como *nome esquemático*, *categoria* , *joining type*,.... Em python esse banco de dados é acessado pelo módulo [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) normatizado pelo padrão [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode13.0.0/).

Comment: Só pra ser pedante, o Unicode vai muito além do mapeamento "caractere→número", já que também define regras de *collation* (ordem alfabética de acordo com o *locale*), separação silábica e outras formas de quebra de texto e [muito mais](https://unicode.org/reports). Mas claro que, para o contexto da pergunta - e até para simplificação didática - não é "errado" dizer que ele define um grande "tabelão" que mapeia cada caractere para um número (sendo que os planos e blocos seriam "apenas" sub-divisões desse "tabelão") :-) Ver [aqui](/q/394834/112052) para mais detalhes. cc @AugustoVasques

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [método `encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) retorna uma instância de `bytes`. E um objeto do tipo `bytes`, [segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes) é uma sequência de **números**, cujos valores estão no intervalo entre 0 e 255.

E um número não "está" em um formato específico, ou em determinada base. É claro que no fim das contas, tudo acaba virando um monte de bytes, mas a forma como esses bytes são interpretados e exibidos varia conforme a situação.

O número 97, por exemplo, pode ser interpretado como a letra "a" (se considerarmos a tabela ASCII), ou como o próprio valor numérico 97 (que por sua vez pode ser escrito como `61` em hexadecimal, ou `01100001` em binário, ou `141` em octal, ou `97.0`, `00097`, `97,00`, etc). Ou ele ainda poderia ser um código específico que varia conforme o contexto (por exemplo, poderia representar o código de uma cor em RGB). Ou seja, os bits seriam os mesmos, mas a forma como eles são exibidos pode variar.

No caso específico de um objeto `bytes`, ao ser impresso, os valores que correspondem a caracteres ASCII imprimíveis são mostrados como os próprios caracteres, e outros valores são mostrados em hexadecimal, com o prefixo `\x`. Essa foi a escolha da linguagem para exibir os valores quando estes fazem parte de um objeto `bytes`.

Se você quer outro formato, terá que formatar você mesmo. Duas opções são usar [*f-string*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) (a partir do Python 3.6) ou [`bin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin). Exemplo:

```
for b in "café".encode("latin-1"):
    print(f'{b:08b}  {bin(b)}')
```

A diferença é que `bin` coloca o prefixo `0b` e não preenche com zeros à esquerda. A saída para o código acima será:

```
01100011  0b1100011
01100001  0b1100001
01100110  0b1100110
11101001  0b11101001
```

Claro que uma vez escolhida a maneira de formatar, você pode construir a string da forma que bem entender. Por exemplo:

```
# 01100011 01100001 01100110 11101001
print(' '.join(f'{b:08b}' for b in "café".encode("latin-1")))
```

Para versões anteriores a 3.6 você pode usar `'{:08b}'.format(b)` no lugar de `f'{b:08b}'`.

---

Outra opção, se quiser tudo junto, é converter o objeto `bytes` para hexadecimal (usando o [método `hex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex)), depois converter para `int` e por fim passar esse número para `bin`:

```
# 1100011011000010110011011101001
print(bin(int("café".encode("latin-1").hex(), 16))[2:])
```

E ainda usei o *slice* `[2:]`  para remover o prefixo `0b`. Mas creio que unir tudo com `join` me parece mais simples do que converter para hexadecimal, para depois converter para `int`, para depois converter para binário.

---

Já para converter para hexadecimal, bastaria trocar a formatação, ou então usar `hex` diretamente:

```
encoded = "café".encode("latin-1")
print(encoded.hex()) # 636166e9

# a partir do Python 3.8, você pode escolher o separador
print(encoded.hex(' ')) # 63 61 66 e9
print(encoded.hex('-')) # 63-61-66-e9

# para versões anteriores a 3.8, você pode usar join para ter o separador
print('-'.join(f'{b:02x}' for b in encoded)) # 63-61-66-e9
print('-'.join(f'{b:02X}' for b in encoded)) # 63-61-66-E9
```

A diferença é que `hex` sempre coloca os dígitos de `a` a `f` como letras minúsculas, enquanto que usando *f-string* você pode escolher tanto minúsculas quanto maiúsculas (usando o formato `x` ou `X`). [Leia a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) para saber mais sobre as opções de formatação.

---

Por fim, vale lembrar que sempre é possível pegar o valor de cada byte individualmente, obtendo o seu respectivo valor numérico:

```
encoded = "café".encode("latin-1")
print(encoded[1]) # 97
print(type(encoded[1])) # <class 'int'>
```

E uma vez tendo esse número, você pode formatá-lo como quiser (usando *f-string*, por exemplo).

E repare como o número exibido individualmente é mostrado como o valor numérico `97`, não mais como o caractere ASCII `a`, o que mostra que de fato o tipo muda a forma como o byte é interpretado e exibido. O fato deste valor estar dentro de um objeto `bytes` não faz com que ele "fique na base 2", por isso ele não satisfez a sua expectativa de que ele fosse exibido em binário.